# Given independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $f_X=\mathcal{X}_{[0,1]}$ and $f_Y=\frac{1}{2} \mathcal{X}_{[0,2]}$, find $P(Y> X).$

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I am currently stuck on a computational problem for my measure theory course and wanted some feedback. The problem is as follows:

> Given independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $f_X=\mathcal{X}_{[0,1]}$ and $f_Y=\frac{1}{2} \mathcal{X}_{[0,2]}$, find $P(Y > X)$ (where $\mathcal{X}$ is the indicator function)

Here is my work thus far:

Since we know that $f_{X+Y}(z):=\displaystyle \int_{{\Bbb{R}}}f_X(x) f_Y(z-x)\,dx,$ we consider the density of the sum given for the independent random variables $X, Y$ in our case as $$f_{Y+(-X)}(z) = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)f_{-X}(z-y)\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2} \mathcal{X}_{[0,2]}(y) \mathcal{X}_{[-1,0]}(z-y) \, dy.$$ Therefore we can see that $$
f_{Y-X}(z):=
\
    \begin{cases}
        0 & z<-1 \ \text{or} \ 2 <z\\
        \frac{1}{2}(z+1) & -1\leq z\leq 0 \\
        \frac{1}{2} & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
        \frac{1}{2}(2-z) & 1\leq z\leq 2. \\
    \end{cases}
\
$$

Since we have the following information we can write that

$$P(Y > X) = P(Y-X>0) = \int_0^\infty f_{Y-X}(z) \, dz.$$ However this is where I get stuck. In my textbook, the author writes that $$ \int_0^\infty f_{Y-X}(z)\,dz=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}+ \int_1^2 \frac{1}{2}(2-z) \, dz.$$

Where does the the $\color{red}{red}$ one half come from and why do the bounds for the integral its being added to run from $1$ to $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty f_{Y-X}(z) \, dz
= \int_0^1 f_{Y-X}(z) \, dz + \int_1^2 f_{Y-X}(z) \, dz + \int_2^\infty f_{Y-X}(z) \, dz.$$
Plugging in $1/2$ for the integrand in the first integral yields $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} \, dz = \frac{1}{2}$. The second integral yields the second term $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{2} (2-z) \, dz$. The third integral is zero.

By the way, I usually see `\chi` instead of `\mathcal{X}` for the indicator function.

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much - this makes sense. Also, I will make sure to use \chi instead of \mathcal{X} next time!

Comment: @TaylorRendon By the way, you (and the textbook) seem to be computing $P(Y>X)$ rather than $P(X>Y)$.

Comment: Whoops! Good catch. I'll fix that now.

Comment: This is certainly the hard way if all you're trying to do is find the probability.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yeah the geometric approach in your answer (+1) is how I would do this myself. But given that OP's textbook seems to be using the same approach as OP, it seems it is mainly an exercise to practice using the convolution formula.

Answer (score 2):

The pair $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the rectangle $[0,1]\times[0,2],$ whose area is $2.$ The set $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,2] : y>x\}$ is the interior of a trapezoid whose are is $1.5.$ Thus the probability is $1.5/2= 3/4.$